# app containing an unsafe implementation of TrustManager

Tags: android, google-play, trustmanager

My app is rejected by google play store. Am getting the following error

> We rejected PowerConnect Univoice App, with package name
>   com.powerconnect2.android.app, for violating our Malicious Behavior
>   policy. If you submitted an update, the previous version of your app
>   is still available on Google Play.

Error originates from the classes below. Anyone who have faced this issue before ?

```
package zoiper;

import java.security.cert.X509Certificate;
import javax.net.ssl.X509TrustManager;

class hi implements X509TrustManager {
  hi() {
  }

  public X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
    return new X509Certificate[0];
  }

  public void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] x509CertificateArr, String str) {
  }

  public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] x509CertificateArr, String str) {
  }
}
```

**My second class**

```
package zoiper;

import java.security.cert.X509Certificate;
import javax.net.ssl.X509TrustManager;

class fmn implements X509TrustManager {
  fmn() {
  }

  public X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
    return new X509Certificate[0];
  }

  public void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] x509CertificateArr, String str) {
  }

  public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] x509CertificateArr, String str) {
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. missed it. let me try it out

Comment: @MorrisonChang The answer you linked is equally insecure. It may trick Google Play into accepting the app, but it's still insecure.

Comment: Removed comment with links as noted by @Nohus as solutions at best were for development only and not acceptable for production code which OP was trying to resolve.